# Removing terms from the expansion of an analytic function of several variables is still analytic?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

Suppose $f(s,t) = \sum_{p,q} a_{p,q} s^p t^q$ is analytic in a neighborhood of $(s,t)=(0,0)$. If we let $b_{p,q}$ either equals $0$ or $a_{p,q}$, does there exist such $b_{p,q}$ so that $g(s,t) = \sum_{p,q} b_{p,q} s^p t^q$ is no longer analytic in any neighborhood of $(s,t)=(0,0)$?

Comment: $f(s,t)$ is analytic on an open containing $(0,0)$ iff there is some $r>0$ and $C_r$ such that $|a_{p,q}|\le C_r r^{-p-q}$. If there is no such $r$ then the coefficients don't tend to $0$ at $(r,r)$ so the series diverges there, if there is such a $r$ then the series converges absolutely (upper bound $\frac{C_r}{(1-|s|)(1-|t|)}$) and is analytic for $|s|<r,|t|<r$

Comment: Got it, thank you so much!

Comment: I meant upper bound $\frac{C_r}{(1-|s|/r)(1-|t|/r)}$ and "the terms of the series don't tend to $0$ at $(r,r)$"